# Figure out name of project in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to figure out the name of the project while in SSIS either through a script task, or a variable?

I know how to get the PackageName, and the TaskName, but in this case, I need the ProjectName.

Comment: Do you can query `SSISDB` database?. If you can do that I'll post a possible solution.

Comment: This needs to work while being used on developer machines as well.

Comment: Yes, I can query the SSIS database.

Answer (score 3):

This is, admittedly, holy-set-the-house-on-fire-hacktastic, but it works when run via SSDT...  You need a couple of things for this Script Task to work:
1. A variable to access so you can climb to its parent.
2. A reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using RuntimeWrapper = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

    public void Main()
    {
        RuntimeWrapper.IDTSProject100 p = ((RuntimeWrapper.IDTSProject100)((Package)Dts.Variables["User::myVar"].Parent).Project);
        string projectName = GetProjectName(p);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    private string GetProjectName(RuntimeWrapper.IDTSProject100 proj) 
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pInfo = proj.GetType().GetProperty("Project", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        Project p = (Project)pInfo.GetValue(proj, null);

        return p.Name;
    }


    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution I tried a while ago.

Just Map  `System::VersionGUID` to `@Version` and `System::PackageID` to `@Package` as the below query.

```
DECLARE @Package uniqueidentifier = ?
DECLARE @Version uniqueidentifier = ?
DECLARE @ProjectName nvarchar(100) = (
SELECT proj.name 
FROM [catalog].[packages] pkg
INNER JOIN catalog.projects proj ON pkg.project_id = proj.project_id
WHERE package_guid= @Package
AND version_guid = @Version
)

SELECT ISNULL(@ProjectName, 'running from ssdt') as ProjectName;
```

If the project is deployed in SSIS Catalogs and it is **not** running from SSDT you will get the project name, otherwise it will return null using the `ISNULL` function you can put whatever. I hope this can help you someway.

**EDIT:** `version_guid` clarification

The `version_guid` will be different if the project has been deployed in several folders.

Looking for documentation [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.versionguid.aspx) site is very short about `version_guid` property.

> Gets the version GUID generated when the package is first created.
>   This field is read-only.

Asumming the creation of the package in the SSISDB will be at deployment the version_guid should be different for every project deployment.

I didn't test in deep but I recreated that scenario: deploy the same project in two different folders.

[image]

Note package_guid and version_guid columns.

Comment: Don't you risk getting the wrong value if you have the project deployed under multiple folders?

Comment: Check my update. version_guid changes in every deployment.