# Is there a system variable for Project Name?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to get the project name for a SSIS package for logging purposes. 
I know there are system variables for the package name, but i cant figure out a way to get the project name.

Comment: Here is the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33417202) for *Script Task* returning project name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Figure out name of project in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400222/figure-out-name-of-project-in-ssis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in way to get this.  Easiest way is to create a project parameter that contains the project name.

Comment: you are right.. that is a easy common sense way to do this, without going into c# or VB.